# Pass attribute, not value as parameter

Tags: javascript

I would like to make this happen in JavaScript:

```
function changeAttributeValue(theAttribute, numberOfPixels)
{
    theAttribute = numberOfPixels + "px";
}

changeAttributeValue(myImage.style.left, 50);
changeAttributeValue(myImage.style.top, 80);
changeAttributeValue(myCanvas.width, 600);
```

The first two calls should move an image and the third should adjust the width of a canvas.

Like this however, just the **value** of the passed variables were passed, so nothing happens.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Well, [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Comment: @JaredFarrish Won't work because they are attribute assignments, not functions. (It should would be handy if one could auto-lift a setter/getter function for a property ..)

Comment: @pst - Are you following me? `:P`

Comment: @pst - This is what I had in mind: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/tCz6j/

Comment: @JaredFarrish Ahh, wasn't quite following that .. your comment did give me some inspiration though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
function changeAttributeValue(obj, propName, numberOfPixels) {
    obj[propName] = numberOfPixels + "px";
}

changeAttributeValue(myImage.style, "left", 50);
changeAttributeValue(myImage.style, "top", 80);
changeAttributeValue(myCanvas, "width", 600);
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, here is my "solution".

It is inspired by Jared Farrish's comment. That is, this creates a "wrapper" getter/setter function for attribute access that can be used. I do not recommend it here (as it is more complicated than what is needed), but it could be used for something awesome elsewhere.

```
function mkAccessor(obj, attribute) {
    return function (value) {
        if (arguments.length > 0) {
            obj[attribute] = value
        }
        return obj[attribute]
    }
}

function changeAttribute (accessor, value) {
    accessor(value)
}

changeAttribute(mkAccessor(myImage.style, "top"), 50)
changeAttribute(mkAccessor(myImage.style, "left"), 80)
var canvasWidthAccessor = mkAccessor(myCanvas, "width")
// somewhere later on
changeAttribute(canvasWidthAccessor, 600)
// or just
canvasWidthAccessor(600)
```

Theory is sound, but code is untested. YMMV. :-)

Comment: Possibly a little more "rounded out" than my original example: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/tCz6j/1/

Comment: You weren't kidding about not using semicolons... `:P`

Comment: @JaredFarrish In some ways only. The fiddle code takes advantage of `this`, which is an interesting approach.

Comment: I think we're being ignored. LOL

Comment: Im trying to understand... but in your example you make a function with 2 parameters yet pass 3.. still staring at it EDIT: ah i see now, every function has a call function if you want, the first variable passed there will be the element you call the function for, it will be the 'this'

Comment: EDIT 2: i still only do not get the reason for setTimeout

Comment: @Jeroen - The only reason I used the `setTimeout` was to show the change; no other reason.

Comment: Yes indeed i was talking about Jared's example. Now i try to understand your solution, especially the 'return function' with inside that the 'return obj[attr]' part. Also, the accessor(value) could be: accessor = value?

Comment: @Jeroen - And yes, `func.call()` and `func.apply()` uses the first parameter passed to get the scope (ie, the `element` itself) for the function called, so `this` references that first parameter's scope. pst is doing something a bit more complex.

Comment: Ah thanks, yes indeed with setTimeout the change shows better obviously, sorry. I was thinking maybe it was necessary to use the function call() for some reason, because there is use of 'this'. i thought 'document' is this, or the current object, so maybe setTimeout was necessary to 'get out' of the current this... ehm so now you know the reason i dont comment and reply right away ;) ... not ignoring you though :)

Comment: @Jeroen - I went ahead and provided a more descriptive answer. Let me know in the comments what questions you have.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably useful if I actually post and comment what I provided in comments.

To wit:

```
function setDim(attr, modifier, pix) {
    if (!modifier) {
        this[attr] = pix + 'px';
    } else {
        this[attr][modifier] = pix + 'px';
    }
}
```

Now, how does this work? The `this` references the scope. If you simply call it directly:

```
setDim('style', 'width', 50);
```

That will simply call the `window` or `global` scope. Really, this is built for passing the scope using [`el.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`el.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), more or less the same, just depends on how you want the arguments passed into the function.

How you really want to call it:

```
// Gives you the scope of the element #test1
var test = document.getElementById('test1');
```

Which then can be "called" like:

```
setDim.call(test, 'style', 'width', 50);
```

Note, if it's just an attribute (plain and simple), pass `null`:

```
setDim.call(test, 'width', null, 50);
```

I use `setTimeout()` in this fiddle for effect, but it's not needed:

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/tCz6j/2/

Take a look through the jQuery core source and see how much [`.apply()` is used](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js). These two methods are *really* useful, if you "get" them.

Comment: Thank you very much, good to have learned about this. I only have a minor question; i wouldve thought that i should pass 'false' instead of  'null'. A quick search on the internet seems to say that null is also evaluated as false.. So i guess its both possible. However, is it better to use null (for what reason?), or was that just a random choice?

Comment: Either way; you could also pass `0`, since that will "flip" to `1` and evaluate as `true`. Anything that evaluates in the opposite as `true` will work; `null` flipped gives `true`. It's easy to remember. Keep in mind, this is "truthy", so `===` is NOT equal to `==` in some cases.

Comment: Thanks very much for your clear explanation of the call() option.

Comment: @Jeroen - This is a little "weird", you can just upvote it but keep timrwood's answer. `:)`

Comment: I tried to but it stated i have to have more reputation... So my only option was to 'accept' 1 answer, i cant upvote yet... The reason im using the first answer by the way: call() to me seems like a function that makes it prossible to call your own defined function on an object. My function shouldnt really belong to an object though

Comment: @Jeroen - The only answer to that then is to pass the object in the parameter list, ie, `setDim(theObj, etc, etc, etc)`. `.call()` and `.apply()` give you additional benefits, but that's probably more wonk than necessary here.

Comment: Because, my function will do more, like accelerate/decelerate the object in a certain time, so to me it feels more like the function will move the object, not that the object should be able to move itself

Comment: @Jeroen - That's not explicitly the case, but I agree that it's hard to see.

Comment: Btw, this is the first time im using stackoverflow. I will upvote your post as soon as im able to, so more people can learn these things. Thanks again